# Apache: Drop extension but file and folder with same name

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

Hy guys,
I'm finishing to build a static html website under Apache (GoDaddy Linux hosting) but recently I have a problem.

I dropped html extension from my files, however, I have multiple folders with the same name of these files in my directory.

When I try to access any of them, of course, I get the error 403.

Is there any way to solve this through the htaccess file?

My htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

I tried several commands suggested in searches by Google, but all were intended to php sites and none worked in my case.

Do you can help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: If you request a URL that maps to both a file and directory, which one do you want served? ALways the file?

Comment: Hi Jon. Well, both are important and, in a way, are bound. Let me explain better: This is a music website. The file contains the profile of the artist and the folder containing the music and lyrics. So when the user clicks the artist, I prefer to open the file. Only if user wants to access the music and lyrics, it is that it opens the folder.

Comment: Jon Lin, thinking well, mapping always the file is a good option for me. Do you can show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the problem isn't with your current rules, but that mod_dir is redirecting requests before your rules even get a chance to process the request.

By default, mod_dir will redirect any request for a directory that's missing the trailing slash to the same request *with* the trailing slash. That could be what's causing the issue so you need to turn that off.

As long as you have the `Indexes` option turned off, it should be ok to turn of directory slashes, otherwise it's possible to expose the directory contents. So try:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks. I'll try your code later 'cause I'm not with my notebook right now. I'll return to say if it worked. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi Jon. Sorry for delay. My job "killed me" these days. But your code worked like a charm. Thank you very much. =)